# d3.js Merging County Polygons into Districts

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to merge counties from a "us.json" TopoJSON file into their respective agricultural districts. I've followed the "Merging States II" code found here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416440 and it works as intended. The only problem is that it takes 10-15 seconds to load in the browser because of all the processing that is going on.

I have to believe there is a more efficient way to do this task; maybe even merging the polygons ahead of time using TopoJSON, but I'm not as familiar with that program so I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

The html and JSON lookup files can be found at the GitHub Gist below

https://gist.github.com/nautilytics/6719443

Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson), the format makes easier (and efficient) to store both counties and districts in the same file.

Comment: You could also have a look at a GIS application such as [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), which will allow you to merge several files.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I used ArcGIS to create the merged district file, but then I couldn't figure out how to create a TopoJSON file from the three different shapefiles I created - one for states, one for counties, and one for districts. Plus those shapefiles were massive.

Comment: You can use ArcGIS to create a single shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I was able to export the three different shapefile layers from ArcGIS and then toss them into http://mapshaper.org/ to simplify them. Then I used the TopoJSON command line tool to combine them all into a single JSON file. Works amazing.

Final output: http://nautilytics.com/NASS-Corn-Acres-Planted/